How to debug a Python package source code in VS Code correctly?
I am trying to debug a Python code, and I want to make some breakpoints in the source code of a package X.
The package is installed in a conda env within the root directory of my project. At the beginning I could not navigate to the source code of a class/method in the source code by right click > go to definition. But it works when I add the conda env in the workspace of my VS Code.
The problem now is I can't access the source code in debug mode with breakpoints. I have succefully added the "justMyCode": false but still do not work.
My configuration looks like this:
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python Debugger: Current File",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": false
        }
    ]


Hello, what's the name of this package, and does it need to be downloaded via pip install? You can check if the application points to the correct source code location. You can configure the launch.json file by adding "module":"x", "pythonPath":"${workspaceFolder}/path/to/x/package". Try this setting to see if it works?

Already tried it but did not work for me. The package in question is graphrag installed via pip install.
I have shared the solution that worked for me. Thanks

Solved by adding both of these lines in launch.json
"justMyCode": false,
"purpose": ["debug-in-terminal"]  

